# Can anyone tell me what an 0R-Jumper Varient C is?

Tags: components, schematics, footprint

I found this component in a schematic I am looking at and have searched the internet far and wide to find out what it is, alas to no avail. If anyone could explain this component and why one would use it that would be awesome. Here is the link to it: https://www.diymodules.org/eagle-show-object?type=std&file=jump-0r-smd.lbr&package=C0R-JMP

Comment: Sounds like a 0 ohm resistor. Often fitted to one of several locations on a PCB to customise it. Either looks like a real resistor, or it can be a place to put a blob of solder.

Comment: The name is suggesting that it is a jumper. I.e. a conductor connecting two given points.

Comment: Perfect thank you everyone for your informative answers!

Answer (score 2):

for 2 position jumpers with 3 pads use Variant 1 or 2.

for 1 position jumpers with 2 pads use Variant 3.

Answer (score 1):

0R-Jumper is a "zero-ohm" resistor, typically used on PCBs to allow for different configurations based on how these components are populated. An example could be one of these components being the sole connection between two local ground planes on a board.

Here's an example datasheet for \$0\Omega\$ chip resistors: https://www.vishay.com/docs/31017/rcwp99.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It is nothing but a zero ohm resistor, also called a jumper.  "Variant C" probably refers to the physical shape.  You can probably find that out by checking the properties of the part when you place it in Eagle.

I can't tell from the linked image what it is supposed to look like.  It is most likely a surface mount part - I don't see any holes for through hole connections.